# Как работать с contentProvider?

Tags: android

У меня есть приложение и библиотека. В библиотеке мне надо получить доступ к SharedPreferences этого приложения. Мне подсказали, что это реализуется через contentprovider. А как мне обратиться из класса не унаследованного от  Activity к этому  contentprovider, в который я занесу sharedpreferences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Через контекст приложения который Вы должны передать как аргумент при создании обьекта этого класса (не унаследованного от Activity).

Comment: Спасибо! работает.